# How to persist the "state" of a chat through the API of OpenAI?

Tags: openai-api

ChatGPT is clearly internally using checkpoints to persists the state of the LLM at every chat interaction. This is how ChatGPT can branch into distinct flows of conversation, re-using the same history. OpenAI is not internally re-submitting the whole chat history.

Do the OpenAI API provides a similar capabilities? I would like avoid paying for a complete re-submission of the whole conversation over and over.